# Closure/interior of $\mathbb{Q}\times\{1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under a different metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the following metric:
\begin{equation}
d_1((x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2))=
\begin{cases}
|y_1-y_2| & \text{if $x_1=x_2$} \\
|y_1| + |x_1-x_2| + |y_2| & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and I am looking for the closure and interior of $C=\{(x,1):x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ but haven't really gotten to an answer. I know the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and I am sensing that the closure of $C$ might be $\{(x,1):x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ but don't really know how to approach it correctly with the different metric, which in the case of $C$ is
\begin{equation}
d_1((x_1, 1), (x_2, 1))=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x_1=x_2$} \\
2+|x_1-x_2| & \text{otherwise, basically the standard metric in $\mathbb{R}$ + 2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Would appreciate some guidance with it, as I am not used to tackling questions using different metrics.

Comment: Hint: Given your explicit description of the metric on $C$, what can you say about convergent sequences in $C$?

Comment: Isn't it that $d((x_n,1),(x,1))\rightarrow 2$ and not $0$? Are there actually convergent sequences with this metric? (Supposing $(x_n)_{n\geq 0} \rightarrow x$ in the standard metric)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about limit points. Also, I didn't quite get the clarification about convergent sequences. Also, would it be that the interior of $C$, $Cº=\emptyset$?

Comment: We are going to have to start with how your class in introducing these terms.  Wh is the definition of an open set? What is the definition of a closed set?  What is the definition of a closure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863525/closure-of-a-set-with-the-jungle-river-metric