# Closure of a set with the jungle-river metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the jungle river metric $d_j$.
$$d_j(x,y) = \begin{cases} |x_2-y_2|, & \text{if $x_1 = y_1$;} \\
|x_2| + |y_2| + |x_1-y_1|, & \text{if $x_1 \neq y_1 $} \end{cases}$$
Let
$$C = \{(x, 1) : x ∈ Q\}$$
What is the closure and the interior of C?

I think the closure is C as ${\overline{C}}$ = C ∪ {all limit points of C}. For any (x,1) in C we can find an "open ball" that only intersects C at (x,1) by taking B(x,ε) for ε<2. Does this mean C has no limit points and that ${\overline{C}}$=C?

For the interior I used the fact that if A ⊂ X then A$^◦$ = X \ ${\overline{(X \backslash A)}}$. I believe ${\overline{(\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash C)}}=\mathbb{R}^2$ which would make C$^◦$ = $∅$.

Comment: Third time this question is posted in a week. Is it an assignment?

Comment: I’m inclined to answer this one as the OP has given a specific thought process that deserves addressing, but I’d like to first see OP’s thoughts on the interior part of the question. @Jack W can you elaborate on what you’ve tried for the interior? (Best to elaborate in the question, rather than as a reply in the comments)

Comment: Ok I have added the part for the interior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862342/closure-interior-of-mathbbq-times-1-in-mathbbr2-under-a-different

Comment: @Mike that one doesn't have answers yet.  Regardless, I really don't think this should be closed, since it's asking pretty narrowly about a specific approach to the problem that is likely not duplicated elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note: I realize this has been asked before this week, but as OP has given a specific thought process that is not duplicated elsewhere that I’m aware of, and that deserves addressing, I’m inclined to answer.]

While your conclusion is correct, your reasoning isn’t quite right for the closure of $C$.

The fact that you can take a ball around any point in $C$ and it only intersects $C$ in that one point doesn’t tell you that $C$ is closed, it tells you rather that $C$ is discrete. For example, the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in \mathbb N\}\subset \mathbb R$ is discrete by this same argument, but is not closed, as it does not contain its limit point $0$.

Instead, you could observe that if $p\notin C$, then either $p=(x,y)$ for $y\neq 1$, whereby the open ball $B(p,|y-1|)$ does not intersect $C$, or $p=(x,1)$ for $x\notin \mathbb Q$, whereby the ball of radius $1$ does not intersect $C$.  Therefore $\mathbb R^2\backslash C$ is open, hence $C$ is closed.

For the interior, what you have written is not wrong, but it somewhat begs the question of how you determined that $\overline{\mathbb R^2\backslash C}=\mathbb R^2$ in the first place.  To conclude this, you could observe that $(x,1)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (x,1-\frac{1}{n})$.

##### Update.

On reflection, with a little care you could make your original argument for the closure work as well.  The fact that every point $p\in C$ has some ball around it intersecting $C$ only at $p$, *of the same radius independent of $p$*, indicates a stronger condition than discreteness - what we might call $\varepsilon$-discreteness (here for $\varepsilon=2$).  An $\varepsilon$-discrete metric space is complete (since every Cauchy sequence is eventually constant), hence any $\varepsilon$-discrete subset of a metric space must be closed.